# How to access variable without using $ (dollar) sign

Tags: variables, tcl

Can I access a variable in Tcl without using `$` (dollar) sign? 
Can I assign one variable value to new variable without using dollar sign?

Example:

```
set x 10
```

I need to access value of `x` without dollar sign.

Comment: Can you detail why you can't use the $ when referencing ?  Can you give an example of what you'd like to do ?

Comment: @NiallByrne : i can use $, wanted to know different ways to access variable.

Answer (score 4):

Well, yes. The `$x` notation is actually shorthand for the invocation `set x`, so you can do this:

```
set x 10      ;# assign to variable
puts [set x]  ;# access the value
set y [set x] ;# assign value to other variable
```

Comment: Indeed, the `set x` way of writing things came first and the `$x` (with its syntactic restrictions) came later.